# Why is $I(S) = I(\overline{S})$, where $R \in Spec(A)$ and $I(R) = \cap_{\mathfrak{p} \in R}\mathfrak{p}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This exact statement is made as a "quick remark" on page 127 of Ravi Vakil's [notes on Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGfeb0717public.pdf). However, I'm not seeing a "quick" way to prove it--the only method I've come up with is to use exercises afterward, which say that if $V$ takes a subset of a ring $A$ to its vanishing set then $$I(\overline{S}) = IVI(S) = \sqrt{I(S)} = I(S)$$

where the last equality is attained since all prime ideals are radical ideals. Is there a quicker way to see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any ideal $J\subset A$, we have $I(V(J)) = \bigcap\limits_{\mathfrak{p}\in V(J)}{\mathfrak{p}}\supset J$, since every $\mathfrak{p}\in V(J)$ contains $J$ by definition. In particular, $I(V(I(S)))\supset I(S)$. Now, for every $\mathfrak{p}\in S$, we have $\mathfrak{p}\supset I(S)\implies\mathfrak{p}\in V(I(S))$, and hence $S\subset V(I(S))$. Since $V(I(S))$ is closed, this implies that $\overline{S}\subset V(I(S))$ as well. By inclusion-reversion, it follows that
$$ I(\overline{S})\supset I(V(I(S)))\supset I(S). $$
Conversely, since $S\subset\overline{S}$, by inclusion-reversion we have $I(\overline{S})\subset I(S)$. It must follow that $I(\overline{S}) = I(S)$.